# get a comma separated string using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code using java `Stream`.

I am trying the get the function to build a string of value: "a,b" in this case.
however, the output (`separatedByComma` in this case) is always "b".

Could somebody shed some light please?

```
@Test
public void testJoin() {
    List<MOccS> occList = new ArrayList<> (  );
    MOccS mOccS = new MOccS ();
    mOccS.setOccSCd ( "1" );
    mOccS.setOccSNm ( "a" );
    occList.add ( mOccS );

    MOccS mOccS2 = new MOccS ();
    mOccS2.setOccSCd ( "2" );
    mOccS2.setOccSNm ( "b" );
    occList.add ( mOccS2 );


    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<> (  );
    strings.add ( "1" );
    strings.add ( "2" );

    String separatedByComma = "";
    for(String word: strings) {
        separatedByComma = occList.stream ()
                                  .filter ( occ -> word.equalsIgnoreCase ( occ.getOccSCd () ) )         
                                  .map ( occ -> occ.getOccSNm () )
                                  .collect ( Collectors.joining ( "," ) );
     }

     System.out.println (separatedByComma);
}


class MOccS{
    String occSCd;
    String occSNm;
    ...
    getter/setter
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Each iteration of your `for` loop overwrites the value of `separatedByComma`. The first iteration assigns the `String` "a" to it, and the second replaces it with "b".

You should `Stream` over the elements of the `strings` `List` in order to join the `String`s that match each of them into a single output `String`:

```
String separatedByComma = 
    strings.stream()
           .flatMap(word -> occList.stream()
                                   .filter(occ -> word.equalsIgnoreCase (occ.getOccSCd()))
                                   .map (occ -> occ.getOccSNm()))
           .collect(Collectors.joining (","));
```

Output:

```
a,b
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution produces exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

In your loop `for(String word: strings)` you overwrite your `separatedByComma` variable.

Comment: I think you are right, could you let me know how to fix it?
sorry I am new to java stream...

Comment: If you want to filter `occList` and allow only those which `getOccSCd` is in list of string I can give you code sample.

Comment: thanks so much for your quick answer as well. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `String.join(",", strings)`